Minimizing a function with absolute L^q penalty in one variable
I would like to solve the following minimization problem to analyze LASSO-type estimators:
$$\arg \min_{x} \quad f(x) = (x-a)^2 + b|x|^q $$
$$\text{where} \quad a \in (-\infty, \infty), b \in (0,\infty),  q \in (0,1] \quad \text{are fixed.}$$
I have confirmed that the solution to this problem can be expressed as follows when q=1 (, which may be known as Soft Thresholding):
$$
x =
\begin{cases}
a + \frac{b}{2},  & \mathrm{a < -b/2} \\
0, & \mathrm{|a| \leq b/2} \\
a - \frac{b}{2} & \mathrm{a > b/2}
\end{cases}
$$
When $q<1$, can the above problem be solved analytically? That is, can we explicitly write x by a, b, and q?

The FOC for the stationary point would be
$$2x-2a+bq\sign(x)|x|^{q-1}=0$$
Which, assuming $x>0$ and letting $q=\frac34$ and $y=x^{\frac14}$ gives
$$y^5-ay+\frac38 b =0$$
In general, quintics of this form have no solution that can be written in terms of roots, so I presume there is no formula in terms of standard functions.
E.g. for  $a=-1$ and $b=\frac83$ it gives $y^5+y-1$.
